# Ubuntu Install firmware for ath10k_pci

Tags: drivers, 18.04

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04, how can I install firmware for ath10k_pci? There is a post for U14.04, but I'm not sure I can do the same in the answers. 
thx for help

```
[    4.074863] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/pre-cal-pci-0000:03:00.0.bin failed with error -2
[    4.074873] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/cal-pci-0000:03:00.0.bin failed with error -2
[    4.076874] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware-6.bin failed with error -2
```

---

for    dmesg | grep ath10k   ->

```
[    3.792117] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    3.792420] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: pci irq msi oper_irq_mode 2 irq_mode 0 reset_mode 0
[    4.074863] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/pre-cal-pci-0000:03:00.0.bin failed with error -2
[    4.074873] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/cal-pci-0000:03:00.0.bin failed with error -2
[    4.076874] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware-6.bin failed with error -2
[    4.078895] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: qca9377 hw1.1 target 0x05020001 chip_id 0x003821ff sub 17aa:0901
[    4.078898] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: kconfig debug 0 debugfs 1 tracing 1 dfs 0 testmode 0
[    4.079373] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: firmware ver WLAN.TF.1.0-00002-QCATFSWPZ-5 api 5 features ignore-otp crc32 c3e0d04f
[    4.146481] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: board_file api 2 bmi_id N/A crc32 8aedfa4a
[    4.780156] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: htt-ver 3.44 wmi-op 4 htt-op 3 cal otp max-sta 32 raw 0 hwcrypto 1
[    4.790875] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0 wlp3s0: renamed from wlan0
[  964.323485] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: failed to install key for vdev 0 peer 9c:c7:a6:92:ce:82: -110
```

Comment: What is your kernel version? `uname -a`?

Comment: And please post the output of `dmesg | grep ath10k` to your question.

Comment: uname -a  :  Linux lenovo-v510-i5 4.15.0-22-generic #24-Ubuntu SMP Wed May 16 12:15:17 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: Does the device work?

Comment: Put new information and output of commands into your question **[as an edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1045319/edit)**, and not as new answers, please.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like everything is OK with your device.

Kernel developers added code to look for some files that don't exist yet for the future.

`ath10k` doesn't work without firmware. In your case it is loaded.

Nothing has to be done.

Comment: the problem is I cant copy datas on my nas using wlan, with a cable it works. so I thought it's because of the wlan-card...